# How to make a class that inherits NumPy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, class, inheritance

Now I'm trying to load a hex data file to `NumPy` array in Python.
(The data file is actually a game save file.)
Before making a class, my code worked well.
But, when I transfer the code to a class, it doesn't work anymore.

I hope to use `NumPy` in my new class, but I think it doesn't necessarily need inheritance way.

Thank you for your advices.

---

At first, the following is my original code before making the class.

```
# Using Numpy Array
import numpy as np

# province_offset_data
province_offset_init = []
province_offset_data = []

for i in list(range(0,41)) :
    province_offset_init.append(11668 + 35*i)
    province_offset_data.append(list(range(province_offset_init[i], province_offset_init[i]+35)))

province_offset_data_array = np.array(province_offset_data)

# call the save data on each offset location
with open(path,'rb') as f:
    province_law_data = f.read()
    province_data = []
    
    for i in list(range(0,41)) :
        province_data_row = [] 
        for j in list(range(0,35)) :    
            province_data_row.append(province_law_data[province_offset_data[i][j]])
        province_data.append(province_data_row)

province_data_array = np.array(province_data)
```

The output is sucessful.

[image: NumPy Array Output]

---

And, I tried it transferring it to a class like the below :

```
# Class - fail

import numpy as np

class rtk2(np) :
    
    def __init__(self) :
        self.province_offset_init = []
        self.province_offset_data = []

        for i in list(range(0,41)) :
            self.province_offset_init.append(11668 + 35*i)
            self.province_offset_data.append(list(range(self.province_offset_init[i], self.province_offset_init[i]+35)))

        self.province_offset_data_array = np.array(self.province_offset_data)

    # call the save data on each offset location
    def dataload(self, path) :
        self.path = path
        
        with open(self.path,'rb') as self.f:
            self.province_law_data = self.f.read()
            self.province_data = []
    
            for i in list(range(0,41)) :
                self.province_data_row = [] 
                for j in list(range(0,35)) :    
                    self.province_data_row.append(self.province_law_data[self.province_offset_data[i][j]])
                self.province_data.append(self.province_data_row)

        self.province_data_array = self.np.array(self.province_data)
        
        return self.province_data_array
```

But it retuns an error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-90-f6a17f11d77c>", line 1, in <module>
    class rtk2(np) :

TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: numpy is a module, not a class, you can't inherit from it.

Comment: Your class can create and use numpy arrays without subclassing numpy or its array class.

Comment: Thank you for you guy's answers.  

I changed the row `class rtk2(np) :` to `class rtk2 :`, so it works well.

Comment: class Geo(np.ndarray) … is how I produced a Geo class that inherits from numpy's ndarray.  read...  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html about subclassing numpy arrays